# What are a stag's comrades called?

Tags: idioms, nouns

Before a man gets married he is referred to as the 'stag'; what are his comrades called?

Comment: Do you mean at a stag party?  What are the other party-goers called?

Comment: @Kit - yeah, that's what I mean.

Comment: His wingmen? :P

Comment: The stag's mate is the *doe* :)

Comment: _Staggerers_, by the end of the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find anything other than *male friends* or *men*:

> **stag party** |støg ˈpɑrdi|
>   noun
>   a celebration held for a man shortly before his wedding, attended by his male friends only.
>   • any party attended by men only.

<sup>*NOAD*</sup>

Edit:

Well, now, hold on. [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=-5sOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22stag%20party%22&hl=en&ei=L3XxTaS_AePV0QGC0um5BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22stag%20party%22&f=false) (from an 1897 slang dictionary) might be getting us somewhere:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=-5sOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22stag%20party%22&hl=en&ei=L3XxTaS_AePV0QGC0um5BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22stag%20party%22&f=false]

If there's anything to this etymology, then it's quite clear that the other stag partygoers are the *feeble fools of the herd*.

Answer (score 1):

A (new ?) humorous usage via the movie "The Hangover" is *the wolfpack*.

Comment: I like that! Maybe this one will stick :)